# Use regex to change img src

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to change image source according to a letter button that I click on.
I guess that I need to use regular expression, but I am not sure how exactly it should look like.

```
<img id="logo_layer2" src="images/logo/logo_compass_a_layer2_red.png">
<ul id="letters">
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
...
</ul>
```

"a_layer2" part should change to "b_layer2", "e_layer2" and so on.

```
events: {
    "click #letters li" : "change_letter"
},

change_letter: function(e) {
    var letter = $(e.target).text();       
    var newimg = /images\/logo\/logo_\w*_\w{1}_layer\d_\w*.png/.replace((/\w{1}/,letter));
    $("#logo_layer2").attr("src",newimg);
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uLqBY/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/gnPks/)</kbd>

```
$('#letters li').click(function(){
    var txt =$(this).text().toLowerCase();
    $('#logo_layer2').attr('src',function(_,old_src){
        return old_src.replace(/_\w_/g,'_'+txt+'_');
    });
});
```

---

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/gnPks/1)</kbd>

```
$('#letters li').click(function(){
    var txt =$(this).text().toLowerCase();
    $('#logo_layer2').prop('src',function(_,old_src){
        return old_src.replace(/_\w_/g,'_'+txt+'_');
    });
});
```

[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Read [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: Thanks! It works, but it's just not getting $(this).text() value.

Comment: As the new src it returns "images/logo/logo_compass__layer2_red.png"

Comment: Yes, I just wonder when I click on "B", why it returns "images/logo/logo_compass__layer2_red.png", when your code should change it to "images/logo/logo_compass_b_layer2_red.png".

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://127.0.0.1/images/logo/logo_compass__layer2_red.png

Comment: I changed it to 
var txt = $(e.target).text().toLowerCase();
Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

To improve on the regex, you can utilise positive lookbehind and lookaheads as follows:

```
(?<=images\/logo\/logo_\w*_)\w{1}(?=_layer\d_\w*.png)
```

This will match simply the letter that you intend to change, in this case it is the 'a' in the src.

As for the jquery/js, I don't know.